# Intergating WSO2 CEP with HTTP REST API

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I'm searching for ways to integrate CEP engine in my application and I would like to know if exists REST API or other tools to integrate it and to access to its functionalities out of management console.

I haven't found nothing on documentation.

Comment: You can integrate using Event receivers which could be http, soap or any other protocol. Please refer receivers documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Configuring+Event+Receivers

Comment: @adellarocca I don't undesrstand why this question is closed. I was looking for exactly the same thing. I found the answer by going to: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Calling+Admin+Services+from+Apps  which directed me to: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Calling+Admin+Services+from+Apps. I can't tell yet if all the functionality I am after is exposed through SOAP APIs but I have found the following regarding events: EventStatisticsAdminService,EventProcessorAdminService,EventStreamAdminService,EventBrokerService,EventPublisherAdminService,EventSimulatorAdminService,

Comment: EventReceiverAdminService,EventFlowAdminService,EventTracerAdminService. Hope it helps